# FCM notification of existing registration

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, whatsapp

Can I register to FCM notification for existing registration from diffrent device ? e.g. I've one device(with Sim) with whatsapp. I want listen in second device for notifications came to the first one. I dont want install whatpp on the second device I just want to get notification not the data itself. Thx

Comment: Are you *listening* for notifications from the actual whatsapp or were you using it just as an example (i.e. you're planning to detect notifications from your own app)?

Comment: what I want is to get notification of my device in other server. I wonder if I can register for the events my device is getting from FCM. I just want get the push notification I dont need the data itself

Answer (score 0):

push notification is received and shown by android application. Usually it raised by application service. This application should be installed on mobile device and register itself at FCM server to get token.

Theoretically you can make android application. App have to get **PROJECT_ID** from resources of whatsapp???.apk and then retrieve Instance ID from fcm server as an instance of Whatsapp. And you will receive notifications.

There is a sample, PROJECT_ID is in mock-google-services.json
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android